# setState is not permanent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, setstate

I am trying to create a sidemenu which has collapsible options.

Below is my code:

```
export default class CRSideMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fprActive: true
    };
    autoBind(this);
  }

  toggleFPR() {
    console.log('Setting fprActive from ', this.state.fprActive, ' to ', !this.state.fprActive);
    this.setState({
      fprActive: !this.state.fprActive
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render', this.state.fprActive);
    return (
      <ul className='list-group list-group-nav'>
        <li>
          <a 
            href='#' 
            className={classnames('list-group-item', this.state.fprActive && 'active', 'has-subnav')}
            onClick={this.toggleFPR} >
            FPR
          </a>
          <ul className='list-group list-group-nav'>
            <li>
              <a href='' className='list-group-item'>FR</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

When I printed out the `this.state.fprActive` in the render() method, I see the following:

- Setting fprActive from true to false
- render false
- render true

How come my fprActive is being automatically setback to 'true' when I click only once?

Comment: I assume `autoBind` makes `toggleFDR` bound to `this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem at this end, but the symptom says that your page is being refreshed when you click the anchor because you're not preventing the default action. Have `toggleFPR` call `preventDefault` on the event object it receives:

```
toggleFPR(event) {
//        ^^^^^ ------------ ***
  event.preventDefault(); // ***
  console.log('Setting fprActive from ', this.state.fprActive, ' to ', !this.state.fprActive);
  this.setState({
    fprActive: !this.state.fprActive
  });
}
```

---

Separately: You're breaking one of [the fundamental React rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) here:

```
console.log('Setting fprActive from ', this.state.fprActive, ' to ', !this.state.fprActive);
this.setState({
  fprActive: !this.state.fprActive
});
```

When setting state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version, not the version you pass an object into:

```
this.setState(({fprActive}) => {
  console.log('Setting fprActive from ', fprActive, ' to ', !fprActive);
  return {fprActive: !fprActive};
});
```

If you don't, it'll work most of the time, and fail in hard-to-diagnose ways sometimes.

Comment: This works perfectly! Something i noticed is that when i swapped the <a></a> tags for a <div></div> tag, there is no page re-rendering (without the event.preventDefault()). Seems that under the hood <a> tags are called

Comment: @AKJ - I've added a note to the end of the answer, your `setState` call is breaking one of the fundamental React rules, so you'll want to fix that. Happy coding!

Comment: thank you so much for the code improvement. Can I know where did the `({fprActive})` come from? And also I have made those changes, but I want to understand it rather than copy blindly :)

Comment: @AKJ - That's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parameter list. The callback version of `setState` gets the then-current state object as its argument. Using `{fprActive}` in the parameter list takes just the `fprActive` property from it. BTW, I'm glad this worked, because I wasn't able to replicate the problem in isolation... :-)

Comment: in other words, if i have other attributes (say attr1 & attr2) in the` this.state = {...}` in the constructor, I could do this as well: `this.setState(({fprActive, attr1, attr2}) => {...});`?

Comment: @AKJ - If by "attributes" you mean "properties", yes: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/qud7xtes/1/